# Can SystemVerilog enums be null?

Tags: enums, system-verilog

I'm using enum method `name()` to print the string value of an enum variable.

Should I do a `null` check first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `name()` method cannot return `null`. It will return an empty string if the value does not correspond to an enumerated value. It may be advisable to do an empty string check.

Quoting from [IEEE std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 6.19.5.6 Name()

> The name() method returns the string representation of the given enumeration value. If the given value is not a member of the enumeration, the name() method returns the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to worry about a `null` enum. However, an enum could be un-initialized if it does not have a state corresponding to `0`

For example:

```
typedef enum {STATE0, STATE1} plain_enum;
typedef enum {VAL0=1, VAL1} special_enum;

module test;

  initial begin
    plain_enum plain;
    special_enum special;
    $display("plain: %s", plain.name());
    $display("special: %s", special.name());
  end

endmodule
```

Returns:

```
# plain: STATE0
# special:
```

Because `special_enum` does not have a state corresponding to `0`

Edit/re-run the code here: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/647